# How do I get a string from a thread or return a String form a Thread?

Tags: java, android, java-threads

Im using a webservice that get a data and stores in a `String`. I need to use this `String` but I cant take it. Global variables don't work in Threads. I'm using a traditional Thread `new Thread() { public void run() {`.

Comment: Why are you don't use AsyncTask? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: global variables do not work in threads? when you create it anonymously? really? sir, i do not think so, add the modifier volatile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LocalBroadcastManager to send and receive data.
This way you can avoid memory leak issues.

Here is code for activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private void signal(){
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(YourActivity.this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("Your action name"));
        Intent yourAction = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourIntentService.class);
        String string = "someData";
        yourAction .putExtra("KEY_WITH_URL", string);
        startService(yourAction);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String string = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_WITH_ANSWER");
            //Do your code 

        }
    };

}
```

Here code for thread which download String or whatever

```
public class YourIntentService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Download here

        Intent complete = new Intent ("Your action name");
        complete.putExtra("KEY_WITH_ANSWER", stringToReturn);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(YourIntentService.this).sendBroadcast(complete);

    }

}
```

You can use Thread instead of IntentService.

Comment: Why does `LocalBroadcastManager` prevent memory leak issues? How does a `LocalBroadcastManager` help them solve their problem of passing values between threads?

Comment: 1) he doesn't need to pass callbacks which could cause memory leak issues. 2) he can put String into Intent or send signal to extract String from db or whatever.

Comment: (Put that in your answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Example of AsyncTask:

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, String> {
     // are you know how to use generic types?

     protected String doInBackground(Params[] params){
           // this code will run in seperate thread
           String resultString;
           return resultString;
     }
     protected void onPostExecute(String resultString){
           // this code will call on main thread (UI Thread) in this thread you can update UI e.g. textView.setText(resultString);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- use a Handler created from the main thread. Then pass your data throuh it
- use a weak reference of your activity in your thread; this way you can call directly the main thread - [Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

  ```
  ...
  Activity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
  if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing() && !activity.isDestroyed()) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
              // you are in main thread, pass your data
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Async task:

```
private class Whatever extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
   protected String doInBackground(Void... void) {
       // do your webservice processing
       return your_string;
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       // Retrieves the string in the UI thread
   }
}
```